# When using cmath, why does log10(1/4) not equal log10(0.25)?

Tags: c++

Working with a friend, I was trying to debug why `log10(1/4)` returns `-inf`, while `log10(0.25)` returns the proper answer of `-0.60206`.

I was using this program to test it, and tried moving the values to variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{  
   double t = 1/4;
   double r = 0.25;
   cout << log10(t) << endl;
   cout << log10(r) << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

That returned `-inf` and `-0.60206`.

Why would `1/4` not behave the same as `0.25`?

Comment: `1/4` is integer division.

Comment: `1/4` is `0`. `1.0/4.0` (or `1.0/4`) is `0.25`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1/4` is integer division, and the result is 0, which is then assigned to `t`. The conversion to `double` doesn't occur until after the result's been calculated already. To force floating point division and get 0.25, use `1.0/4`.

This would have been fairly obvious if you tried printing out the value stored in `t` rather than just `log10(t)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because 1 is an `int`, and 4 is an `int`, so it is the same as:

```
int one = 1;
int four = 4;
double x = one / four; // zero
```

Conversion from `int` to `double` happens at the end, after division has already taken place.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ (and most other programming languages), the division of an integer by an integer is always an integer. The result of `1/4` is truncated to produce 0.

Try `1.0 / 4` instead, as a float divided by an integer is always a float.